# Ubuntu Linux segfault when transferring files over SFTP

Tags: systemd, python3, segmentation-fault, glibc

I am trying to transfer movie files over SFTP to my Ubuntu server in order to load them to my Jellyfin Docker instance, but every time I try to transfer a file I get a segfault error.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 with docker installed and a number of containers including a minecraft server, jellyfin, nextcloud, etc.

I also tried stopping all my containers before initiating the file transfer, but I ended up getting the same error.

Here is the error message from /var/log/syslog:

```
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.085824] systemd[1]: segfault at 56433cee21c0 ip 000056413ce26d13 sp 00007ffe10644b20 error 4 in systemd[56413cda0000+e0000]
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.085845] Code: 00 ba 35 03 00 00 48 8d 35 83 d9 05 00 48 8d 3d 0a 42 08 00 e8 8e e1 f7 ff 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 63 57 08 48 8d 05 ad b4 0b 00 <48> 8b 04 d0 48 8b 80 d8 00 00 00 48 83 c4 08 ff e0 66 66 2e 0f 1f
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.105392] apport[4880]: segfault at 40000000 ip 000055743aa460c2 sp 00007ffe1b82fd50 error 4 in python3.10[55743a990000+2b3000]
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.105403] Code: 84 9b 02 00 00 48 8d 1d 9c 79 45 00 eb 31 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 49 8b 6e 60 48 2d b8 01 00 00 48 85 ed 74 0a 48 01 c5 <48> 83 7d 00 00 75 67 48 83 c3 38 48 83 3b 00 0f 84 61 02 00 00 48
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.105413] Process 4880(apport) has RLIMIT_CORE set to 1
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.105414] Aborting core
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.170171] apport[4884]: segfault at 562d536c2428 ip 0000562c51d35780 sp 00007ffe0f00e840 error 4 in python3.10[562c51c75000+2b3000]
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.170179] Code: 00 00 00 4d 85 ff 7e 64 48 8d 3d 4b fd ff ff 48 83 c3 10 48 39 fd 75 6a 31 ed 4c 8d 35 c9 fd ff ff 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 <4c> 8b 23 4d 85 e4 74 2d 4d 8b 44 24 08 41 f6 80 a9 00 00 00 40 74
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.170187] Process 4884(apport) has RLIMIT_CORE set to 1
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.170189] Aborting core
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.189960] systemd-tty-ask[4869]: segfault at 7f25345c6300 ip 00007f25345c6300 sp 00007ffc4f184758 error 14
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.189974] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7f25345c62d6.
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.199006] RIP: 0010:pagecache_get_page+0xaf/0x590
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.199015] Code: c0 48 3d 06 04 00 00 74 e4 48 3d 02 04 00 00 74 dc 48 85 c0 0f 84 0b 03 00 00 41 89 c1 49 89 c7 41 83 e1 01 0f 85 09 03 00 00 <8b> 40 34 85 c0 74 bc 8d 50 01 f0 41 0f b1 50 34 75 f1 48 8b 45 b8
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.199019] RSP: 0018:ffffbef602087bb0 EFLAGS: 00010246
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.199021] RAX: 0000000040000000 RBX: 000000000000000e RCX: 0000000000000000
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.199023] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000000000005ef83 RDI: ffffbef602087be8
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.199025] RBP: ffffbef602087c48 R08: 0000000040000000 R09: 0000000000000000
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.199026] R10: ffff9a79d1e67818 R11: ffff9a7c16121ca8 R12: 0000000001100cca
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.199028] R13: 000000000005ef83 R14: 0000000000001000 R15: 0000000040000000
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.199029] FS:  00007f86483a0cc0(0000) GS:ffff9a7fd1b40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.199031] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.199033] CR2: 0000000040000100 CR3: 0000000119544000 CR4: 0000000000750ee0
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.199034] PKRU: 55555554
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.204084] apport[4887]: segfault at 561f1b612f49 ip 00007efc307347ab sp 00007ffecee947f8 error 4 in libc.so.6[7efc305bf000+195000]
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.204091] Code: d0 c5 f8 77 c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 66 0f 6e e6 89 f9 c4 e2 7d 78 e4 c5 f9 ef c0 83 e1 3f 83 f9 20 77 55 <c5> fe 6f 0f c5 fd 74 d1 c5 dd 74 d9 c5 fd d7 ca c5 fd d7 c3 48 83
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.204098] Process 4887(apport) has RLIMIT_CORE set to 1
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server kernel: [ 1513.204099] Aborting core
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server systemd[1]: Caught <SEGV>, dumped core as pid 4879.
May 23 10:10:11 brandons-server systemd[1]: Freezing execution.
May 23 10:10:52 brandons-server kernel: [ 1553.924907] systemd-journald[581]: Failed to send WATCHDOG=1 notification message: Connection refused
```

I also get this error when I try to restart service sshd from the command line:

```
Assertion 'm->containers' failed at src/libsystemd/sd-bus/bus-message.c:95, function message_get_last_container(). Aborting.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It looks like the error likely has something to do with systemd, python 3.10, and / or libc.so.6, but I'm not sure how to fix the issue. Any tips or ideas are greatly appreciated!